# How to pass useRef props to two components to focus an input ( textarea ) - react.js and typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this component

```
const Pubs = () => {

  const selectArea = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);


  return (
      <LikesComments selectArea={selectArea} publication={publication} />

      <DisplayComments selectArea={selectArea} publication={publication} />
    </PubHero>
  );
};

export default Pubs;
```

And, when i pass the useRef to likesComments, i have this function who will use the useRef as props

```
interface IlikesCommentsProps {
  selectArea: Idontknow
}

const LikesComments: React.FC<IlikesCommentsProps> = ({ selectArea }) => {
  const focusComment = () => {
    selectArea.current.focus()
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={focusComment}>
      <CommentIcon />
      <LikeCommentText separation='0.7rem'>Comentar</LikeCommentText>
    </div>
  )
}

export default LikesComments
```

And when i click that function in the first comment, i want it to focus an input (textarea) in the second component

```
interface IcreateComments {
  selectArea: Idontknow
}

const CreateComments: React.FC<IcreateComments> = ({ selectArea }) => {
  return <textarea ref={selectArea} />
}

export default CreateComments
```

How can i make this happen?

I really haven't tried before to pass useRef as props, so, i really don't know what to do exactly, i've tried to look for answers, but found nothing at all

Can you help me with this?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you looked at `forwardRef`? https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Comment: I have, if i can't get a solution, i will give it a try !

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it. I am showing one.

Firstly you can use a single ref for that. Just you have to take help of an menthod. The method will focus to the textarea.

```js
const handleSelectArea = () => {
  selectArea.current.focus()
}
```

Now pass them to the two component that you want

```
<LikesComments handleSelectArea={handleSelectArea} publication={publication} />
```

Inside the component `onCLick` call the method

```
const focusComment = () => {
  handleSelectArea();
};
```

As you are already passing the ref to the text area so it will focus that.

You have to use the ref as bellow

```
type TextareaProps = React.HTMLProps<HTMLTextAreaElement>

const CreateComments = React.forwardRef<HTMLTextAreaElement, TextareaProps>((props, ref) => {
    return <textarea ref={ref}/>
})
```

[Simple Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-for-sw-solve-12-06-2021-v8phw)

Comment: I have edited the solution, Added a codesandbox link

Comment: I get it, but the problem is, how the interfaces would look like when i pass down to the props ? that's where i'm stuck

Comment: How can i get the ref to my text area, i'm using typescript

Comment: I added more about how to use forwardRef in TS

Comment: I like your solution, but one more question, what am i supossed to pass to the second component as props ( there is where i have the textarea ), i don't have to pass nothing ?

Comment: You will pass the ref to the textarea component and the focusComment function to the other component to trigger the focus from the parent component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233691/discussion-between-moshfiqrony-and-diego).

Comment: If it solved your problem mark it as answer